# Google Fusion Tables - Get the Latitude and Longitude for a geocoded address

Tags: json, google-fusion-tables

I have multiple Google Fusion tables with geocoded address columns of type "LOCATION".  I would like to return the Latitude and Longitude results for those columns when I perform a SQL Query.  Is that possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.  It is not possible.  If you want to retrieve that information from the table, you need to geocode it externally and include the geographic coordinates in the table.

Comment: As far as I can figure this is correct, but it seems nuts that they don't allow you to select this or have it as some form of pseudo-column.