# Load Fusion Table query value into JS variable?

Tags: javascript, google-fusion-tables

I'm attempting to place, what will eventually be a dynamically sized, partial opacity filled circle over the basic default google maps red location marker dot. Initially all locations in the table are marked. 
This code abstract then works fine to filter, and only display one place name at a time - on selection from the table populated drop-down list.  My last section of code will draw a circle, if I insert static geo co-ords.
But been scratching my head and searching in vain over the syntax/method to load the same query response parameter that google maps layer_0 is using, into my variable circlePos. A key hurdle that'd let me get ahead with other tasks too I'm sure. Hands up, my programming is rusty in general, but I've found the learning path of scarce online examples, utilizing rapidly changing API versions... awkward. Hence any help appreciated.

```
function changeMap_0() {
  var whereClause;
  var searchString = document.getElementById('search-string_0').value.replace(/'/g, "\\'");
  if (searchString != '--Select--') {
      whereClause = "'PlaceName' CONTAINS IGNORING CASE '" + searchString + "'";}
      layer_0.setOptions({
      query: {
      select: "col2",   //e.g. 54.742461,-1.884263 
      from: "1Fmd93Cnqv7rhJEFHIixl6wa1x-LuAH24z1AJKtw",
      where: whereClause }
  });
      var circlePos = //syntax to load value from the above query?
      new google.maps.Circle({ 
      center: new google.maps.LatLng(circlePos),          
      radius: 24000,
      map:map
 }); }
```

Answer (score 0):

The FusionTablesLayer object does not expose the information you need. You need the [coordinates of the geocoded address column](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16094565/google-fusion-tables-get-the-latitude-and-longitude-for-a-geocoded-address/16096405#16096405).

You need to query the FusionTable directly using either [GViz (example)](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_FusionTable_badQueryB.html) or the [FusionTables API v1.0](https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/docs/v1/getting_started) to get those coordinates.  The simplest solution is to store them in your table.

The [example](http://www.geocodezip.com/v3_SO_FusionTable_badQueryB.html) above uses the Google Maps API geocoder to geocode the addresses, the results may differ from the position displayed on the FusionTablesLayer.

[SO question containing the example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18945948/fusion-table-with-sidebar-error-in-query/18946160#18946160)

Comment: Ah, :) I understand the layers object doesn't expose that info. I meant I'd like to use the same query response that it can access. i.e. from select on col2 and assign it to variable circlePos. In the table col2 and col3 comprise two column geo Location, and work fine with map to show simple location dots. cols 2 and 3 were already prior geocoded by my rather long spreadsheet formula. Excuse any ambiguity in my writing. (still mending aphasia)

Comment: [This table (the one referenced in your code)](https://www.google.com/fusiontables/DataSource?docid=1Fmd93Cnqv7rhJEFHIixl6wa1x-LuAH24z1AJKtw#rows:id=1) does not include a two column geo location.

Comment: geocodezip, yep, while testing last night I unchecked the two column option in the 'Latitude' column. Basically because I was keen to just move ahead - so in the absence of any obvious 'quick' solution to get Select queries such as that detailed in the code example into a js variable... I've resorted to what appears (to me) the only method and I'm working successfully on using the 'response' object. ie. I've a function named getLocalityData calling/querying the 'response' object, with a callback to hand the result to a function named createCircle that uses the data for fusion's 'circle' method